# Как сделать что бы матрица стала сходящаяся?

Tags: c++, c, алгоритм

В задание надо решить матрицу методом простой итерации. Я все написал но для некоторых матриц это не подходит и преподователь сказал сделать функцию что бы она стала сходящаяся, а я не знаю как это сделать, вот набросал идею, но работает не правильно (использовал процедуру Жордана с коэффициентом R = R * 1.1):

```
void reductionToIterative(double **A, double *B) {
 double R;

 for (int k = 0; k<N; k++)
 {
  for (int i = k + 1; i<N; i++)
  {
   if (A[k][k] != 0)
   {
    R = A[i][k] * 1.1 / A[k][k];
    for (int j = 0; j<N; j++)
     A[i][j] -= A[k][j] * R;
    B[i] -= B[k] * R;
   }   
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: Что значит "решить матрицу"? "Работает неправильно" - что неправильно?

Comment: @VTT Решить систему уравнений в матричной форме. Решить методом простой итерации, но моя матрица не сходится для решения этим методом
и нужно сделать ее сходимой

Comment: Наверно надо домножить матрицу на транспонированную?